# get an element from each array in list of arrays?

Tags: python

I have a list of arrays such as the following:

```
[array([ 3.04347826,  3.04347826,  3.04347826,  3.04347826,  3.04347826,
    3.04347826,  3.04347826,  3.04347826,  3.04347826,  3.04347826,
    3.04347826,  3.04347826,  3.04347826,  3.04347826,  3.04347826,
    3.04347826,  3.04347826,  3.04347826,  3.04347826,  3.04347826,
    3.04347826,  3.04347826,  3.04347826]), array([ 3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,
    3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,
    3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,
    3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5,  3.5]), array([ 3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,
    3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,
    3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,
    3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,
    3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,
    3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,
    3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529,  3.08823529]), array([ 3.84848485,  3.84848485,  3.84848485,  3.84848485,  3.84848485,
    3.84848485,  3.84848485,  3.84848485,  3.84848485,  3.84848485,
    3.84848485,  3.84848485,  3.84848485,  3.84848485,  3.84848485,
    3.84848485,  3.84848485,  3.84848485,  3.84848485,  3.84848485,
    3.84848485,  3.84848485,  3.84848485,  3.8484848....
```

How do I get only the first element of each array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may work, assuming array is a `numpy.array`

```
first_elements = [e[0] for e in list1]
```

where:

`list1` is your list of arrays

`first_elements` is a list with the first element of each array in `list1`

In a clearer way:

```
first_elements = []
for arr in list1:
    first_elements.append(arr[0])
```